# Selenium (python): can't switch to iframe (name is dynamically generated)

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I'm having problem selecting the iframe and accessing the different elements inside it. The iframe name is dynamically generated (e.g. frame11424758092173 or frame0005809321 or frame32138092173). The problem is that Selenium can't find the iframe no matter what i do....

switching to most recent frame doesn't work:

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
```

Waiting for frame gets a timeout exception:

```
try:
        iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.TAG_NAME('iframe')))
    except:
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

The following lines of code also times out:

```
try:
        iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, u"iframe")))
        driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
    except:
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

I have also tried iterating through the frames but it can't find it. The returned  list is empty

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
#iframes is empty
```

really need some help...

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried locating the iframe by its XPath and using the contains method?:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@name, "frame")]')
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
```

Now you can access elements within the iframe.

To exit the iframe use:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

The contains method lets you get an element by a partial attribute value. Pretty useful for dynamically generated IDs, names, etc. You can search by other attributes as well using XPath. For example, say your iframe element has the attribute `value = "3"`. You could use:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@name, "frame")][@value = "3"]')
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
```

This approach can be used with any number of attributes as well.

You could also try getting the element by its selector. Keep in mind that this limits what you can do with it:

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("INSERT SELECTOR HERE").doSomething();')
```

To get the Selector and/or XPath you're going to want to inpect the element using your browser (Chrome in my case). Right click on the element. Click Inspect. Then right click on the HTML element and click Copy > Copy Xpath or Copy > Copy Selector.

If that doesn't work for me, my last resort is to go the url of the iframe.To get that, you need to right-click on the area of the webpage where the iframe exists and click `View Frame Source`. It'll then lead you to a new page. The url of that page will be shown in the top of the browser after `view-source:`. You can then simply navigate to that url:

```
driver.get('insert url of iframe here')
```

And now you have access to the elements within the iframe. I do not recommend this approach if you are manipulating elements within the iframe and then exiting the iframe. Your changes will get lost. This will only work if you are scraping info off of that iframe, NOT if you are manipulating the elements within. Finding the iframe element and switching into it is usually better and safer.